# Translate another div on click using jQuery and CSS3

Tags: jquery, css, click, transform

I'm trying to mimic the lovely mobile menu implementation on http://mashable.com/ (reduce the width of your browser to see the menu button on the top left, and click on it).

Basically, I have a button (#slide-menu). The rest of the page content is wrapped in a '#nudge' div that I want to slide over 250 pixels to the right when the button is clicked.

```
jQuery('#slide-menu').click(function() {
        jQuery('#nudge').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(250px, 0)');
        jQuery('#mobile-menu').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

The #mobile-menu is containing the navigation which is to pop out from the left of the screen. 
This code works, but there isn't a smooth transition. The content just pops to the right and the menu appears, but doesn't have any sort of delay to give a smooth slide like on mashable. I've also tried toggling a class instead of using the .css() to allow for the multiple prefixes, but have had even less luck.

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how the transform property works. I've tried reading into it, but most examples I can find are related to hovering over an element and making it animate, as opposed to manipulating on element on click of another.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I was indeed missing a transition duration!

```
    jQuery('#slide-menu').click(function() {
        jQuery('#nudge').toggleClass('slide-menu');
    });
```

and the css:

```
.slide-menu{
    transform: translate(180px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(180px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(180px, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(180px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(180px, 0);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

Et voila!